# Codeigniter 4 querybuilder join not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have two tables (Entities, Division) like this

**Entities**

| id | name | is_freezone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC LTD | 0 |
| 2 | A & B LLC | 0 |
| 3 | C & D LLC | 0 |

**Divisions**

| id | name | entity_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TOYS | 2 |
| 2 | FOOD | 2 |
| 3 | HOUSEHOLD | 3 |

I want the query to get the name of entity with the foriegn key (entity_id). I want the data to be displayed like :

| id | name | entity_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TOYS | A &B LLC |
| 2 | FOOD | A & B LLC |
| 3 | HOUSEHOLD | C & D LLC |

My code :

```
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table('divisions');
        $builder->select('*');
        $builder->join('entities', 'divisions.entity_id = entities.id');
        $query = $builder->get()->getResult();
```

But this not returning the expected result. Can anyone can help me to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `$query = $builder->get()->getResult();` do `echo $builder->getCompiledSelect();` - copy it into a DB tool or PHPMyAdmin and run the query and see what comes back / errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();
            $builder = $db->table('divisions');
            $builder->select('divisions.id as id, divisions.name as name, entities.name as entity_name');
            $builder->join('entities', 'divisions.entity_id = entities.id');
            $query = $builder->get()->getResult();

//try this, hope it work
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an alias to differentiate the repeated name field and debug the output
print_r($query);